# PayPal Direct unauthorized payment error nopcommerce

Tags: .net, paypal, payment, nopcommerce, unauthorized

I have successfully configure sandbox PayPal Direct on nopcommerce. I have test this with the test accounts and test credit cards PayPal sandbox provides.

I test this while the website is available on the internet.

Then when I switch to live `ClientId` and `Secret`, I remove the sanbox checkbox from the PayPal Direct from administrator nopcommerce admin panel,

nopCommerce PayPal Direct configuration:

[image]

But when I try a payment with a credit card that has balance the payment is not processed.

In the nopcommerce administrator panel the log after the payment try is the following: 
nopcommerce log:

[image]

My PayPal account is business account. In the PayPal developers the ApiCalls section has the following rows/history of the unsuccessful calls (with the status-warning) without further details:

PayPal live api calls history:

[image]

PayPal Live account, where the `ClientId` and `secret` is provided is from RestAPI section in PayPal developers as the image bellow:

PayPal live `ClientId` and `secret`:

[image]

Furthermore, in the 'account eligibility' has the options as shown in the next image

Account eligibility:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: *I already have PayPal Payments Pro*, Could you please show us your account type?

Comment: Also add Webhook Id

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from nopCommerce Premium Support about this

nopCommerce Premium Support Replied:

we contacted PayPal support in order to make sure that the plugin is outdated. Probably it will not be out of the box anymore.
Meanwhile if you want to use PayPal direct you have 3 choices:

1. Create an integration by yourself
2. Request a quote on the following page - http://www.nopcommerce.com/requestquote.aspx
3. Find a plugin on our marketplace:
   https://www.nopcommerce.com/marketplace.aspx?searchterm=paypal